# Folder Permissions

Tags: permissions, folder

I have created a number of folders in a team SharePoint site.

Weirdly I can no longer see one of these folders despite having permissions set to Full Control for the site and the folder.

Comment: Maybe you're using a view without folders? i.e. all files flatten at the root of the view. This can be changed in the view settings.

Answer (score 0):

- Got to list or library setting:
- Modify your view
- Update Show items with folder property.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on ***Modify View*** from the ribbon.
2. Expand Folders section and select **Show Items with Folders**.
3. Click Ok. You should see the folders now.

Even now if you are not seeing any folders on your library. there is something wrong you are doing either with permissions or other elements.

Please be specific if this does not solve your query.